# PHP: MYSQL Row into Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have a little problem, hope you can help me... In my mysql table row named `size` I have:

> "XS"=>"11", "S"=>"22", "M"=>"33", "L"=>"44"

I would like to get that out in an array, so I can post it to my select.

```
$x = mysqli_query($mysql_link, "SELECT * FROM dagenshug_produkt WHERE varenummer = '$produktid'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($x)) {
    $sizearray = array($row['size']);
    print_r($sizearray);
}
```

This returns:

> Array ( [0] => "XS"=>"11", "S"=>"22", "M"=>"33", "L"=>"44" )

But i would like

> Array ("XS"=>"11", "S"=>"22", "M"=>"33", "L"=>"44")

Anyone who can help me a little?

[image: Picture of the db design]

[The new db design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PYpv.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more information about your database schema (result of `DESC dagenshug_produkt;` for example). It seems that your data is not stored in an appropriate manner for what you want to do.

Comment: I cannot believe the return you posted is the actual return you get. There's either a bracket missing and/or a comma.

Comment: So does that mean you have 1 row with 4 columns or 4 rows each with one column

Comment: no i just got one row, with the text "XS"=>"11", "S"=>"22", "M"=>"33", "L"=>"44", and i just want that into an array as i pull it out of the db.. but dunno who to do it ;/

Comment: @RiggsFolly My guess is one Field with 4 colums stored as "array-string".

Comment: @MarkJacobsen Can you change your db design? And can you show us what the table definition looks like?

Comment: I just posted a picture ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the picture, but as RiggsFolly said, put it in the question and delete the 'answer'.

Comment: @Jeff Its worse than that "he's dead Jim, dead Jim"

Comment: You'd better have one field per size in your table than trying to save a string-parsed array into one field. If you cant do that, save a json and parse that.

Comment: @jeff That sux!, then i have to do a lots of check, and lots of the products do not come in size, like voks ;)

Comment: Then make it a json! A json is much easier to parse than an stringified array (which is not a standard I think). Please read my 'answer' so that I can delete it later... And checkout `json_encode` and `json_decode`!

Comment: I have read it, thanks, :) - I think i just redesign my db, because i am not that good at js ..

Comment: this has nothing to do with js! It has is name and origin in js, but you don't need one line of js to make use of it. It's just a standard to store data.

Comment: The wheel has already been invented... If you don't know how to implement a feature (in your case product sizes which is a specific application of *products variations*, which color or matter are too), take a look at what others do: Prestashop, Magento, OpenCart, and many others.

Comment: yiiir, i see.. i about to read a little about it, so you think the best why is to store the size in the db with json_encode, and then decode it again when i pull out of the db ?

Comment: Once again, this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you ask how to get the data, whereas the actual question is *how data should be stored*.

Comment: It's not the best way, as you will face a lot of limitations when you go that way. Filtering, searching, ... It's just the easiest fix to the original question. Re-designing your data-structure is the best way.

Comment: @Arcesilas thanks for the XY Problem! Never heard of it, often saw it (in here especially), and I guess sometimes had it myself...

Comment: @Jeff, i tried to redesign the structure,(Look the new picture in the question) so now i can check if the product, comes i different size, and if it doesn't then the code just pass that script and move on ;)

Comment: good for now! If your products are more diverse (color, material) you will need an extra table anyway. Because maybe you want to add a stock-value for every size somewhen? Or one size is not available for a special product, ....

Comment: @jeff - why not just continue in the same table, keep adding rows, will it slow the db ? if the same product comes in a new color, then it need to be added with a new ID ;) and then grouped with the other color :)

Comment: This is product variation: take a look at how other solutions deal with it. If you add a new product with a new ID, you will have one product page for each... Nonsense, your customers won't like it.

Answer (score 0):

I post this as an answer, as it will be to loong for a comment.
I will delete it later, as it will not be a real answer to your question.

You need to redesign your database. Please read about relational database design.

One (easy) possibility is to have one table-field per size.
The downside to this design is, that if f.e. one product invents a new size called XMS you're f* and need to rewrite a lot of code.
This is where relational tables come in place. If you have an extra table that saves all the sizes per product, you're fine!

such a sizes-table could look like that:

```
product_sizes
----------------
id          // unique id of this entry (int, auto_incement)
label       // 'XS', ...
size        // '22',...
product_id  // the id of the product it refers to
```

But all that thoughts depend on your requirements that we don't know.

Comment: This is *many-to-many* relation: 1 product can have one or more sizes, and each size can be applied to one or more products... There should be 3 tables, to link the 2 entities: `products`, `sizes` and the relation table `products_sizes`

Comment: I expected that each product would have it's own set of sizes. Like italian 'small' is completely different to american 'small'. But we don't know what Mark's data really will look like. We pointed him the direction I guess. Thanks for mentioning MYSQL workbench - I was searching for such a (free) tool for ages, none of those I've found I really liked, now trying this one!

Comment: I've never seen any ecommerce software doing this. Products variations are not a simple feature of ecommerce software to implement. It requires many tables (much more than just 3 like in the examples we gave). As I said, the wheel as already been invented. To be perfect, the shop should be able to display the appropriate size depending on the buyer's country (EU shoe size is not the same as UK or US, whereas an XL t-shirt in the US cannot also be L in EU: size is written on the label, period). But such a feature would be even more complicated to implement and probably require even more tables.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for the wrong question. As raised in the comments, you need to redesign your database.

You don't necessarily have to develop a universal products variations (colors, sizes, matters, etc.).

Your products are in a table, they all have a unique ID. Good. In another table, store your sizes:

- id: integer auto increment (PK)
- size_name: 2XS, XS, L, M, L, XL, XXL, 3XL
- size_description (for information purpose in the backoffice)
- product_type (or product category). Remember that XL is a shirt size, whereas 10 is a shoe size.

The *pivot* table, which materializes the relation between your products and the sizes:

- product_id
- size_id

This table may contain *relation data*, like additional cost (sometimes large sizes are more expansive), etc.

To make it even better, you may store the association *size*<->*product type* with another table. It will be necessary in your backoffice to allow some sizes to be applied to appropriate products.

Anyway. Designing a database **does not** happen in phpMyAdmin. Never. There are specific tools for that, like MySQL Workbench. It will help you have full overview of your database.

You also ***need*** to know the difference between a table which represents an entity and and a table which exists for technical reasons (sorry, my vocabulary is a little limited in this case). A *pivot* table is not en entity, even if it can *carry* data (for example: the date a user was added to a group).

This is very important to know these basics, they will help you build a strong, secure, efficient and fast database.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to help...

```
$x = mysqli_query($mysql_link, "SELECT * FROM dagenshug_produkt WHERE varenummer = '$produktid'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($x);
$arr = explode(",",$row['size']);

$a=array();
foreach($arr as $n) {
$m = explode("=>",$n);
$a[$m[0]]= $m[1];
}

print_r($a);
```